# QTest keyclick with multiple modifiers

Tags: qt

We are trying to automate short cut keys of an QT application. As a result we could be able to automate the shortcuts with single modifier (ex: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>). The code for the same can be found below:

```
QTest::keyPress(window, key, modifier);
QTest::keyRelease(window, key, modifier);
```

Here S's corresponding key will be passed to key variable and equivalent modifier of ctrl will be passed to modifier variable.

Currently we are trying to automate the shortcut with multiple modifiers (ex: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>). Is there any way to achieve by QTest apis?

Comment: Did you try to pass `Qt::ShiftModifier | Qt::ControlModifier` as modifier?

Comment: @vahancho It is working. Thanks for the response.